# Texmaker refusing to do anything on clean OS

Tags: bibtex, miktex, texmaker

I'm running MiKTeX and Texmaker on a clean install of macOS. I can compile through MiKTeX with TeXworks but not through Texmaker. It completely ignores its commands and is blind to log files apparently. How is no one else having these problems? It's literally clean macOS install from yesterday, MiKTeX and Texmaker after. Can't get simpler than that.

Here are my commands:

[image]

At first they were called from aliases, tried going to the files themselves and running that, doesn't make any difference. Keeps complaining that it didn't find a log file or couldn't find a file, even for newly created projects or projects that clearly have a log file in the same directory.

[image]

It's also not an access issue, both MiKTeX and Texmaker have full disk access (which neither should need).

Can see here how Texmaker is supposedly executing the exact same command that I am. It works manually, but Texmaker fails, and it can't be a permission issue.

[image]

Comment: We share your frustration but please remove the expletive.

Comment: Sorry about that. Been stuck on it for hours (:

Comment: That console output doesn’t look like MikTeX but TeX Live.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by randomly switching between some of the compilers (like postscript) for a while until the latex and pdflatex decide to start working. Makes no sense but there it is.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question or explain why you ask about miktex but show texlive running